# Show row number of list item

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list

We have a list which should be display the row number of the item. A calculated column doesn't work.

So I worked with the SharePoint designer. I added different "code" to my column but number 1 returns on all the list items.

Here is the "code":

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($Rows) - position() +1"/>

<xsl:value-of select="position()" />

<xsl:value-of select="count($Rows)"/>
```

Is it possible to get the row number of my list items?

Answer (score 1):

How to get rows count in List View

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row)" />
```