# Number SharePoint list items always starting at the top with 1, 2, 3

Tags: list, list-view, number

I need to add a field to a SharePoint list which always numbers the list items viewed on the page starting at the top with 1, 2, 3... The top row would always be number "1". Is there any way to do this?

Comment: do you mean like [this other question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95704/show-row-number-of-list-item)?

Answer (score 0):

There is already an internal field called ID for every SharePoint list (AFAIK). You can make it visible by modifying your view and making this field visible.

Note: This field gets auto incremented as you add items to the list, you don't need to handle it.

Comment: I wish I could use it but I can't use the ID. The requirement is to number the list items top-down. The top row would always be number "1".

Comment: What do you mean you can't use the ID?

Answer (score 0):

Without adding a Field and when no sort order is specified in the View,
you **may** be able to use an old trick:

- Open your List Settings page

  .../_layouts/15/**listedit**.aspx?List=%7B...%7D
- manually change the URL to:

  .../_layouts/15/**reorder**.aspx?List=%7B...%7D

But the internal **[ID]** field or a custom Order field (and Sorting in the Viewsettings) might be more failsave